# Android SDK - get contacts is very slow

Tags: android, performance, import, contacts

a new app, I need to import all contacts with mobile phone,

I runs the code below in an AsyncTask class.

Its works fine, but very slow, on a device with 2000 contacts, the device freeze for few moments.
I know it can be done much faster since there are a lot of apps that use the contacts.

Any  ideas?

```
    public ArrayList<ContactInfo> getContacts() {
        ArrayList<ContactInfo> arrayList = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
        ContentResolver cr = GlobalData.instance().getContext().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        String id;
        String name;
        int counter = 0;

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        int indexId= cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        int indexName = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int indexHasPhoneNum = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.d("getContacts", "Start");
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            id = cur.getString(indexId);
            name = cur.getString(indexName);
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(indexHasPhoneNum)) > 0) {
                // Query phone here. Covered next
                Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {                   
                    int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                    if(type == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE){
                        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        arrayList.add(new ContactInfo(name, phoneNumber));
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                phones.close();
            }

        }
        Log.d("getContacts", "End (" + counter + ")" );
    }
    cur.close();
    return arrayList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some search with other resources and some common sense, the answer to get all mobile phones in the device is to query the ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI instead of the ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI and ran the cursor on that.